# Why WordPress block JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I allow myself to post this topic because I'm stuck running my script in WordPress. In fact, I have created a function that allows you to display in div packs and inside them are their corresponding tasks.

Basically, I had to create a plugin in WordPress to do this.

I had made a select which, when I chose a client and clicked on "Select", returned what corresponded to this client (packs and respective tasks).

This is what it looked like before clicking on the second pack (from 10/01/2020) :

[image]

And this is what it looked like after clicking on it:

[image]

Here is the code corresponding to that (there are three other functions where I don't put the code since they are not interesting for the understanding of it):

```
function contenuAffichage($idClient){

// Permet d'afficher le temps restant dans le pack du client
$bdd=new wpdb('root','','appchrono','localhost');
$temps = $bdd->get_row("SELECT `tempsContrat` FROM `clients` WHERE`IDUSER`=".$idClient);
$tTemps = get_object_vars($temps);
$affichageTemps = convertisseurTemps(implode("",$tTemps));
$contenu = "<p class='info' id='solde'>SOLDE TEMPS RESTANT :</p>
<p class='info' id='tempsRestant'>".$affichageTemps."</p>";
// Permet d'afficher le(s) pack(s) correspondant(s) au client (par son id) 
$rows = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `IDPACK`,`DESCRIPTIF`,`DATEAJOUT` FROM `packs` WHERE `IDUSER`=".$idClient." AND  `DESCRIPTIF` LIKE '%pack assistance%' ORDER BY `packs`.`DATEAJOUT` DESC");
$contenu.="<div class='info'><p class='note'>Note : temps minimum d’intervention de 15 minutes par demande.</p>
            <p class='note'>Si l’intervention résulte d’un bug ou d’un dysfonctionnement du système, aucun débit temps ne sera effectué.</p></div>";
foreach ($rows as $values) :
        $contenu .=" <button class='accordion' value=".$values->IDPACK.">".$values->DESCRIPTIF." du ".dateFR($values->DATEAJOUT)."</button>";
        // Permet d'afficher la liste des tâches présentes dans le pack
    $lignes = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `DESCRIPTIF`,`TEMPSINTERVENTION`,`DATECREATION` FROM `taches` WHERE `IDPACK`=".$values->IDPACK." ORDER BY `taches`.`DATECREATION` DESC");
    $idPack = $values->IDPACK;
    $contenu.="<div class='panel'>";
    foreach ($lignes as $values) :
        $contenu.="<div id='listeTaches'>
                        <div class='dateTaches'><b>".dateFR($values->DATECREATION)."</b> :</div>
                            <div class='commTaches'>".$values->DESCRIPTIF."</div>
                            <div class='tempsTaches'>(".$values->TEMPSINTERVENTION." min)</div>
                        </div><br>";
    endforeach;
    // Permet d'afficher le report de temps du pack précédent
    $lignes = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `IDUSER`,`DESCRIPTIF`,`DATEAJOUT` FROM `packs` WHERE `IDUSER`=".$idClient." AND  `DESCRIPTIF` LIKE '%Report solde%' AND`REPORTPACK`= ".$idPack);
    foreach ($lignes as $values) :
        $contenu.="<div id='reportPack'>
                    <div class='dateReport'><b>".dateFR($values->DATEAJOUT)."</b> :</div>
                        <div class='commReport'>".$values->DESCRIPTIF."</div>
                        </div><br>";
    endforeach;
    $contenu.="</div>";
endforeach;

if ($contenu !=""){ $affichage= searchReplace($contenu); }

return $affichage;}
```

For lack of time, I had to abandon the plugin design because I couldn't generate correctly shortcodes for each client. So I copied in functions.php of my theme the content of this function. I also created another function to call the css and the style that is applied to this function.

I created two folders (css and js) in my theme that I called in functions.php this way :

```
function load_my_files() {   
   wp_enqueue_script('script', '/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/js/tachesClients.js'); 
   wp_enqueue_style('style', '/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/css/tachesClients.css'); 
} 
add_action('init', 'load_my_files');
```

And thanks to a plugin allowing to write php code under WordPress (XYZ PHP Code), I made a call to the contentDisplay function in the page I wanted.

This integrated CSS and JavaScript but, unfortunately for me, Javascript doesn't "work".

Here is the JavaScript code :

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
       panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
       panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
console.log("fichier JS");
```

Here is what I get on my page :

[image]

The console.log appears well in my console but the accordion effect doesn't work.  Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

I look forward to hearing from you,

Damien

--- EDIT ---

Thank you  Dcdanny for your answer. I edit this post to answer to you.
The accordion buttons don't work if i click them.

This is the console.log's result of "acc" when it work (for the plugin) :

[image]

And the console.log's result when it doesn't work :

[image]

I don't understand why the accordions button can be active for plugin and doesn't work when i put the function into functions.php ....

I tried to add javascript directly in functions.php like that :

```
function wpb_hook_javascript(){
  ?>
  <script>
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;
  console.log(acc);
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
     acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
     });
  }
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head','wpb_hook_javascript');
```

But the result is the same ...

--- EDIT 2 ---
I managed to get around the problem.
Indeed, I removed the JavaScript code and I modified my HTML code. I used the details and summary tags to get the rendering I wanted.
This may help someone so here is my modified code :

```
function contenuAffichage($idClient){
// Permet d'afficher le temps restant dans le pack du client
$bdd=new wpdb('root','','appchrono','localhost');
$temps = $bdd->get_row("SELECT `tempsContrat` FROM `clients` WHERE`IDUSER`=".$idClient);
$tTemps = get_object_vars($temps);
$affichageTemps = convertisseurTemps(implode("",$tTemps));
$contenu = "<p class='info' id='solde'>SOLDE TEMPS RESTANT :</p>
<p class='info' id='tempsRestant'>".$affichageTemps."</p>";
// Permet d'afficher le(s) pack(s) correspondant(s) au client (par son id) 
$rows = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `IDPACK`,`DESCRIPTIF`,`DATEAJOUT` FROM `packs` WHERE `IDUSER`=".$idClient." AND  `DESCRIPTIF` LIKE '%pack assistance%' ORDER BY `packs`.`DATEAJOUT` DESC");
$contenu.="<div class='info'><p class='note'>Note : temps minimum d’intervention de 15 minutes par demande.</p>
        <p class='note'>Si l’intervention résulte d’un bug ou d’un dysfonctionnement du système, aucun débit temps ne sera effectué.</p></div>";
foreach ($rows as $values) :
    $contenu .=" <details id='accordion'>";
    // Permet d'afficher la liste des tâches présentes dans le pack
    $lignes = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `DESCRIPTIF`,`TEMPSINTERVENTION`,`DATECREATION` FROM `taches` WHERE `IDPACK`=".$values->IDPACK." ORDER BY `taches`.`DATECREATION` DESC");
    $idPack = $values->IDPACK;
    $contenu.="<summary id='summary' value=".$values->IDPACK.">".$values->DESCRIPTIF." du ".dateFR($values->DATEAJOUT)."</summary>";
    foreach ($lignes as $values) :
        $contenu.="<div id='listeTaches'>
                    <div class='dateTaches'><b>".dateFR($values->DATECREATION)."</b> :</div>
                        <div class='commTaches'>".$values->DESCRIPTIF."</div>
                        <div class='tempsTaches'>(".$values->TEMPSINTERVENTION." min)</div>
                    </div>";
    endforeach;
    // Permet d'afficher le report de temps du pack précédent
    $lignes = $bdd->get_results("SELECT `IDUSER`,`DESCRIPTIF`,`DATEAJOUT` FROM `packs` WHERE `IDUSER`=".$idClient." AND  `DESCRIPTIF` LIKE '%Report solde%' AND`REPORTPACK`= ".$idPack);
    foreach ($lignes as $values) :
        $contenu.="<div id='reportPack'>
                <div class='dateReport'><b>".dateFR($values->DATEAJOUT)."</b> :</div>
                    <div class='commReport'>".$values->DESCRIPTIF."</div>
                    </div><br>";
    endforeach;
    $contenu.="</details>";
endforeach;

if ($contenu !=""){ $affichage= searchReplace($contenu); }

return $affichage;
}
```

Comment: Do the accordion buttons work if you click them twice or do they not do anything at all? What do you get if you type `acc` into the console?

Comment: Thank you Dcdanny for your answer. I edit this post to answer to you